# A field referencing two tables - Foreign Key Conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Please check the tables below for a simplified version of my problem:

**Table Boys**

```
BoyId
BoyName
...
```

**Table Girls**

```
GirlId
GirlName
```

**Table Toys**

```
ToyId
ToyName
ToyOwnerBoyOrGirl ( The toy could be owned by a boy or a girl)
ToyOwnerId
```

I created two constraints:

1) `ToyOwnerId` is a foreign key of the Primary Key `Boys.BoyId`

2) `ToyOwnerId` is a foreign key of the Primary Key `Girls.GirlId`

My purpose is to tell the database that `ToyOwnerId` will always be one of these Ids

**My problem:** 
When I tried to insert a new Toy with an id of a Boy, I got an error that there is a `foreign key conflict` in the Girls constraint.

Is this a bag design or I can still use the same design with a fix ?

Comment: You cannot create a foreign key that references two tables, no database allows this. You will either have to change your schema (which you've said you can't/won't) or live without the reference. Also note that if you ask "is this a bad design", and when the answer is "yes, it is bad design" your response is "ok, but I can't change it", then perhaps you're not asking the right question.

Comment: I haven't said i can't change the schema "at all". I only mentioned in my comments that using a single table for both entities is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bad design. Why don't have one table for all children and some mark - is it boy or girl? Also I really doubt you need `ToyOwnerBoyOrGirl` field - as it can be easily obtained by join from toys to owners.

Consider following scheme:

```
Table Children
ID
Name
Is_Boy

Table Toys
ID
Name
Owner_ID
```

In this case you need just foreign key from toys to owners, and other tasks you might encounter will be much more simplier to solve.

**EDIT**: As per OP's comment - Boys and Girls tables are totally different.

So, in this case you still can have table `Children` (let's use previous terminology) as a "common" table for `Boys` and `Girls`.

Something like:

```
Table Children

ID   
Table_Name ('Boys' or 'Girls' here)
Record_ID (ID from Boys or Girls respectively)
...maybe some common fields from boys and girls tables here...


Table Boys
ID
Child_ID
...the rest of fields

Table Girls
ID
Child_ID
...the rest of fields
```

Comment: Yes ,but each table has a completely different set of fields, one has up to 80 fields and the other has only 10 fields. Please note that Boy and Girls tables are just synonyms of my actual table names which are more complicated

Answer (score 2):

I think you should combine the boys and girls table to one table called children.  It would have sex column that would have an M or F.   That will simplify things.

Comment: I can't do it, as each table has a completely different set of fields. I just mentioned here the common field names for simplification.

Comment: If you hide facts and then ask us to critique the design, your results will be less than optimum.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply have both IDs in your toys table plus a check constraint to ensure that always either a boy or a girl is the owner.

**Table Toys**

- ToyId
- ToyName
- ToyOwnerBoyId
- ToyOwnerGirlId

```
  CONSTRAINT chkToyOwner CHECK 
  (
    (ToyOwnerBoyId is null and ToyOwnerGirlId is not null)
    OR
    (ToyOwnerBoyId is not null and ToyOwnerGirlId is null)
  )
```

As to selecting the data, use outer joins:

```
select ...
from toys
left join boys on boys.boyid = toys.toyownerboyid
left join girls on girls.girlid = toys.toyownergirlid;
```

To find toys owned by boys:

```
select ...
from toys
where toyownerboyid is not null;
```

Comment: This sounds perfect as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad design, given the fact one column set (one column, being ToyOwnerId) is referred to different tables, both as a one-column FK to a one-column PK. The obvious question would then be : how come you have different tables with a similar PK ? And I see you have answered that already, by means of replying the data columns of the respective tables are different. That is a good reason to have different tables. But, then, how to solve the FK issue ? (I understood that these "boys" and "girls" are not the real entities). What you can do, is make a BoyToy and a GirlToy table. If you have very few data columns (data = non-PK and non-FK) then that is a perfect solution. No ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will be a good solution if it was just a Toy Table, but i got 2 or 3 toy-like tables and this means i will have to double them all

Comment: OK. Well, then it depends how these "toy-like" things relate to each other. You'll need to see the impact on each change : structural table differences lead to very different INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands, and you must behold the ease of that as well. A simple table setup can sometimes lead to coding nightmares. Not to mention : if you can avoid triggers, and rely on PK/FK, the latter is - in my mind - the best solution.